# Showing there exists a surjective linear map based on given mappings

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out how to do this question. I have a feeling that there could be an error in the question. I feel that question is supposed to be asking you to show that these linear maps are surjective, but the first of the three is not linear. I cannot see that there is enough information to be able to show that they are linear.

Can anyone shed some light on whether there is an error, or whether it is possible to show from the given information that i) the maps are linear and ii) they are surjective.

Let $(e_{1},e_{2},e_{3})$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. In each case determine whether there is a surjective linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$.

$(i)$ $T(e_{1}) = (1,1,0)$, $T(e_{2}) = (1,0,1)$, $T(1,2,0) = (2,1,2)$.

$(ii)$ $T(e_{1}) = (1,-1,0)$, $T(e_{2}) = (1,0,-1)$, $T(e_{3}) = (0,1,-1)$.

$(iii)$ $T(e_{1}) = e_{2}$, $T(e_{2}) = e_{3}$, $T(1,2,0) = e_{1}$.

Thanks, Helen!

Comment: Just check whether Linear independent set maps to a linear independent set. If not, such a map doesn't exist.

Comment: It asks you to find a linear AND surjective map. The first one is not linear, so you can proceed to the next one.

Comment: But surely with the amount of information given, you cannot show that any of the maps are linear, you can only show that they are not linear if a clear exception exists from the information given.

Answer (score 1):

Some things you might want to prove, once and for all, for any linear map $T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ (Here $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is the standard basis for $\Bbb R^n$).

$1)\ T$ is injective $\iff \{T(e_1),\dots,T(e_n)\}$ is linearly independent.

$2)\ T$ is surjective $\iff \text{span}(\{T(e_1),\dots,T(e_n)\}) = \Bbb R^m$

$3)\ T$ is bijective $\iff n = m$ and $\{T(e_1),\dots,T(e_n)\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^n$

(the $n = m$ condition is actually redundant, as it follows from the basis requirement, but it's easier to check).

In "this problem" at hand, we have $n = m = 3$, so if $\{T(e_1),T(e_2),T(e_3)\}$ spans $\Bbb R^3$, it must also be a basis, since:

Basis = maximal linearly independent set = minimal spanning set. So in the "special case" where $m = n$, we can test for either (1) or (2), as in that case they are equivalent to (3).

Note that since in this problem we only need to show the EXISTENCE of a linear $T$, for each $T$ given would could DEFINE:

$T(x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3) = x_1T(e_1) + x_2T(e_2) + x_3T(e_3)$, which would guarantee that $T$ is linear (prove this!).

Testing for linear independence or spanning of $\{T(e_1),T(e_2),T(e_3)\}$ involves about the same amount of work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

(i) cannot be linear since
$$T(1,2,0) = T(e_1+2e_2) = (2,1,2) \neq (3,1,2) =T(e_1)+2T(e_2)$$

(ii) must be the linear map associated to the matrix
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & -1
\end{matrix} \right)$$
so, simply look at the determinant: if it is $\neq0$ then the map is surjective, otherwise not.

(iii) cannot be linear, the argument is the same as for (i).